# Hide out of stock variations in WooCommerce variable product pages

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, stock, product-variations

I am working on WooCommerce Footwear Shop and my client has a requirement about variation. He wants to hide out of stock variations.

Currently, I have added a filter to gray out add to cart button, when the selected variation is out of stock, but he wants to hide it instead:

```
/**
 * shortcode for variations when out of stock
 */
add_filter( 'woocommerce_variation_is_active', 'grey_out_variations_when_out_of_stock', 10, 2 );

function grey_out_variations_when_out_of_stock( $grey_out, $variation ) {

    if ( ! $variation->is_in_stock() )
        return false;

    return true;
}
```

Is there any solution for this?

I have tried some other codes, but none of them worked.

Answer (score 2):

To hide out of stock variations from variable product page, try the following instead:

```php
add_filter( 'woocommerce_variation_is_visible', 'hide_out_of_stock_variations', 10, 4 );
function hide_out_of_stock_variations( $is_visible, $variation_id, $product_id, $variation ) {
    if ( ! $variation->is_in_stock() ) {
        $is_visible = false;
    }
    return $is_visible;
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your child theme (or in a plugin).

Tested in storefront theme and work.

**Note:** When using some plugins or some themes, that are making customizations to original variable product page, it might not work, if `woocommerce_variation_is_visible` filter hook has not been implemented in the right way.

Comment: I have added this code in function.php of my child theme, but it's not working. Also removed below code that I showed, clear cache and still not working, is there any other solution.

Comment: Sorry I just tested the code, and it works perfectly, hiding all out of stock variations.

Comment: Unfortunately the php filter doesn't work at my site

Comment: This is because you are using some other related plugin that is making trouble or because of your theme customizations. I tested it in Storefront theme, for info.